# What should I do to run a script on specific time without cron?

Tags: shell-script, shell, cron

I want to run a script without using cron at specific time. But it is not working.

```
#!/bin/sh

DATE=`date | cut -d' ' -f4`

#Date is getting printed, if I run it manually, without any error. But file is not created at scheduled time.

echo $DATE

if [[ $DATE == "07:06:55" ]]
then
echo "this is a test program" >> xyz.log

fi
```

Comment: this https://askubuntu.com/q/844533/283843 can help you?

Comment: If you want to run it daily, please explain why you can't use cron.

Comment: cron is the correct service to use for running a a command daily at a specific time.  If not using cron, you will have to arrange for the script to re-execute itself at a particular time in the future, maybe using `at` (which is part of cron), or by sleeping (which would make the executions drift over time), and you would additionally have to set up an initial execution of the script at reboots (again, this is easy to do with cron, or with some other system service).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `at`:

```
at -f "$script" 'now + 24 hours' &>/dev/null
```

[The at command explained with an example](https://coderwall.com/p/eilosa/scheduling-jobs-in-unix-without-cron)

I found this also:

```
watch -n <the time> <your command or program or executable>
```

[The watch command on the web](http://www.linfo.org/watch.html)

Comment: at still uses the cron facility.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run it only once, you can use the at command : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/At_(command)

Example :

```
echo "echo \"this is a test program\" >> /tmp/xyz.log" | at 1127 apr 11
```

If you want to run it every day, you might need to use a loop :

```
#!/bin/bash

while true;
do
    DATE=`date | cut -d' ' -f4`
    echo $DATE
    if [[ $DATE == "11:33:00" ]]
    then
            echo "this is a test program" >> xyz.log
            sleep 1s
    fi
done
```

Comment: #!/bin/sh

echo "this is a test program" >> xyz.log | at 0745

It didn't work, since I want to run it daily.

Comment: OK, I have updated the answer

Comment: you could : sleep 86398 ? (ie, 24h minus 2 seconds) to help the "furiously looping" version. Sleep is handled by the OS and will not consume cpu during the wait duration! But the real solution is using cron, designed for this and that will not occupy a cpu for each process just waiting to be launched at a specific date&time...